# Understanding and confusion over synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose we have

```
class A {
    synchronized void m1() {
    }
    synchronized void m2() {
    }
    void m3() {
    }
    static void m6() {
        synchronized(this){
        }
    }
}
```

and two instances of class A a1&a2.

Now if thread t1 with instance a1 call the method m1,there is only restriction that thread t2 with instance a1 can't execute method m1 untill t1 finishes the execution of m1. And t2 with instance a2 can execute m1().

Now my doubt is Can thread t1 with a1 can execute other method's(except m1) parallaly while executing m1?

what's difference b/w synchronized block and synchronized method? Is the difference only that the block have lesser scope for synchronization so it is efficient?

I read an article stating "Synchronized block can throw java.lang.NullPointerException if expression provided to block as parameter evaluates to null".

We always use "this" as parameter to synchronized block, so there is only and always case using synchronized block inside a static method.Beacuse we don't need an object instantian to execute static method.

Where did i misunderstood it?

Comment: `we always use "this" as parameter to synchronized block`. Actually synchronizing on `this` is considered bad practice

Comment: `we always use "this" as parameter to synchronized block` Now this is a mistake...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Could you please explain explain what kind of expression we should use as parameter to synchronized block,as i can see the answer by Sotirios Delimanolis directly gave null as parameter. Can you please give an example to make it clear? Please

Comment: @ppeterka66 Though `synchronized(this)` can be a bad practice.  It is only so if the `this` referenced is accessible publically.  Otherwise a delegating child `synchronized(this)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @JohnVint Do you use `this` **always** when synchronizing?

Comment: No I don't, but I also understand when it shouldn't and could be used.

Comment: @RajeshKumar the rule of **common sense** applies: the object that makes sense to synchronise on. It is not necessarily the whole object, and in static cases, as `this` is not available, it might be required to use the Class object...

Comment: @JohnVint `No I don't` then please read what I wrote. I wrote that blindly using `this` for synchromisation without any reasoning done is a dumb idea. Why does writing this imply requiring education regarding this?

Comment: You wrote `Now this is a mistake...`.  That statement requires education. Which is why I comented

Comment: @JohnVint Ok, cool. Answer this: **Is it wise to always use `this` for synchronizing?** However beware: if you answer **no**, you agree with _my original statement_. If you answer **yes**, then you _contradict yourself_. You decide.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I never said it is always wise to use `this` but I also didn't say that is always a mistake.  So not sure why you are giving me only two options.

Comment: @JohnVint because `Is it wise to always use this for synchronizing?` has only 2 answers. ppeterka66 didn't say that it was always a mistake. He said it was a mistake to always use `this`.

Comment: @Cruncher I agree that is what he said, my comment is simply stating it isn't always a mistake.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Just for your information, the code you mentioned in the question doesn't compile. `this` can't be used in static context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now if thread t1 with instance a1 call the method m1,there is only
>   restriction that thread t2 with instance a1 can't execute method m1
>   untill t1 finishes the execution of m1. And t2 with instance a2 can
>   execute m1().

This is correct. Since both threads are `synchronized` on the same instance, the first `Thread` gets to execute and the second `Thread` gets to wait.

> Now my doubt is Can thread t1 with a1 can execute other
>   method's(except m1) parallaly while executing m1?

Yes, this is known as reentrant synchronization. Take a look at the [end of this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

> what's difference b/w synchronized block and synchronized method? Is
>   the difference only that the block have lesser scope for
>   synchronization so it is efficient?

A `synchronized` block can be used on any instance. A `synchronized` method synchronizes on `this` implicitly. Try to use `synchronized` blocks as often as possible only around the actual **critical section**.

> I raed a article stating "Synchronized block can throw
>   java.lang.NullPointerException if expression provided to block as
>   parameter evaluates to null".

The following

```
synchronized(null) {...}
```

would throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Is there an edge case when `synchronized methodName(...){}` is not equivalent to `methodName(...){synchronized(this){}}`? I guess if the method body edits the parameters that could be passed into it? I ask because your answer gives reason as to why a sync block can be better than a sync method, but doesn't really state the other way around.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't think so. Each method call would have its own copy of the parameters.

Comment: @cruncher What did you mean by _other way around_?

Comment: I mean, is there any **real** advantage to using a synchronized method other than saving a line of code?

Comment: @Cruncher None that I know of. [See the example in this JLS chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6). It says they are equivalent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Means t1 with a1 can execute other synchronized method m2 as well while executing m1 parallel. But other threads can't execute any synchronized methods operated on the acquired object lock. Did i understand it correctly? Could you please give an example where we can use synchronized(expression)...i couldn't understand it.

Comment: @RajeshKumar If a thread acquires the monitor of an object, while it holds it (ie. in a `synchronized`), it can reacquire it as many times as it want, regardless of if it's from a method or block. Other threads then have to wait when calling any synchronized methods on that instance.

Comment: @RajeshKumar The link I posted has a number of examples of `synchronized` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

for example, synchronized(this){...} will be run only around the actual critical section, and only on the current instance but synchronized(otherInstance){...} will works with other instance independently of current instance

Answer (score 0):

I think yes.

About synchronize on this ,-if you synchronize on 'this' or indeed any publicly visible object for the internal (or even external) logic of a particular class, you run the risk that something outside the class may "interfere" with things by holding on to the lock. So... whenever you are deciding on the locking mechanism for a particular case, you need to weigh things up and make it clear in your API what that object's locking policy is.